# slideshow sequence with one button JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at numerous similar posts, which most of them have a previous button, but I only need one button to loop back to the original photo once it cycles through. I tried adjusting my code following along with those posts and I kind of understand but I'm still getting error after error whenever I adjust. So I wanted to make a question specific to my issue and hope that someone could explain/give guidance on where I'm going wrong.

```
<script>

var main = document.getElementById("tool");
var imgArray = ["/tools/saw.jpg","/tools/chisels.jpg","/tools/pitchfork.jpg"];
var imgIndex = 0;

function switchImg(){
    main.setAttribute("src",imgArray[imgIndex]);
    imgIndex = (imgIndex +1) % imgArray.length;
    }


</script>

<style>
img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.buttons{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="tool" src="/tools/saw.jpg"  height="248" width="364" alt="Saw"/>


<br/>

<div class="buttons">
<button type="button"  onClick="switchImg();"> Next </button>
```

***Error***

[image]

I thought I might need a *for* statement, but I dont understand how I would call the  id=tool (inside the body) into the for statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html element doesn't exist yet. You need to put your script at the bottom

Like this:

```
<style>
img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.buttons{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="tool" src="/tools/saw.jpg"  height="248" width="364" alt="Saw"/>


<br/>

<div class="buttons">
<button type="button"  onClick="switchImg();"> Next </button>
    <script>

var main = document.getElementById("tool");
var imgArray = ["/tools/saw.jpg","/tools/chisels.jpg","/tools/pitchfork.jpg"];
var imgIndex = 0;

function switchImg(){
    main.setAttribute("src",imgArray[imgIndex]);
    imgIndex = (imgIndex +1) % imgArray.length;
    }


</script>
```

Because of loading HTML it load from the top to bottom, header is first then body and everything inside the body. That's why best practice is to put your  tag at the bottom before the closing  tag

Also you can use

```
window.onload
```

or jQuery

```
$( document ).ready()
```

Comment: Ooooooh! It worked! Thank you! But wait, I thought scripts always had to be at the head of the HTML document? Why would it be different here??

Comment: Please see my update. 
Also you can read about script tag, there are a lot of attributes with can help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: I kind of want to throw my book away at this point. Doesn't mention or practice scripts being outside the header. Thank you for your help and explanation!